# Augment interface definition

Tags: typescript

The following code is valid typescript and works as expected:

```
interface I {
  greet(name: string): void
}

class C implements I {
  greet(name:string) {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}`)
  }
}
```

Now consider the following snippet, where I augment the signature of the `greet` function:

```
interface I {
  greet(name: string): void
}

class C implements I {
  constructor() {
    this.greet = this.greet.bind(this, 'Jon');
  }
  greet(me: string, name:string) {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}, I'm ${me}`)
  }
}
```

This code does NOT compile since the interface `I` isn't implemented correctly:

```
Class 'C' incorrectly implements interface 'I'.
Types of property 'greet' are incompatible.
Type '(me: string, name: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(name: string) => void'.
```

Is there any way I could annotate my method and tell the compiler the extra argument was injected and the interface is still valid?

Comment: injected? no. you can make the 2nd argument of the method optional and the compiler will stop complaining. Also the first argument will have to be the name parameter, otherwise you'll receive the name in the me parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I could annotate my method and tell the compiler the extra argument was injected and the interface is still valid

Don't change the signature of the function. Just change what the function uses. e.g.

```
interface I {
  greet(name: string): void
}

class C implements I {
  me: string;
  constructor() {
    this.me = "jon";
  }
  greet(name:string) {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}, I'm ${this.me}`)
  }
}
```